# Using Tortoise SVN to merge a contribution to an open source project on to the main branch

Tags: svn, open-source

What is the correct way to combine the files from two different SVN repositories?

I'm a SVN newbie.  I taught myself how to use Tortoise SVN so I could checkout open source projects.  I managed to checkout the main trunk of WEKA and it works fine.

There is a contribution of another set of algorithms.  This contribution has a different URL for the repository and the instructions state one should install it "over the top" of the main WEKA installation.  I can checkout the contribution by itself but if I try to checkout the contribution and put in the same directory (on my computer) as the main project, I get an error message from Tortoise SVN stating "this directory is in use for another URL".

All the instructions I read in the red-bean SVN manual about merging are talking about merging a branch of the trunk.  But even though the contribution has a similar file structure and the files from the contribution are meant to be placed in the same subfolders on my computer, it isn't really a branch from the trunk.

What is the correct way to combine the files?

I suppose I could zip the contribution files and then unzip then into the folder on my computer containing the trunk files but this doesn't seem like the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `svn export http:/path/to/repo/` to a local directory and copy the files and folders manually. A more elegant solution might apply a diff tool like kdiff3 for copying.

Answer (score 0):

The [svn2svn](http://svn2svn.codeplex.com/) tool seems to do what you're looking for.